# Linked List Beginner

Tags: c, list

I just started learning Linked List and I am having issues making a function that will read my linked list. When I select the read function from switch it goes blank and nothing happens ( If I would put the code in main () it would work ). What am I doing wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct nod
{
    int nr;
    struct nod *next;
} nod;

int read(struct nod *p)
{
    while(p->next != NULL )
    {
        printf("%d", p->nr);
        p=p->next;
    }

    printf("%d", p->nr);
}

int main()
{
    struct nod* trei = NULL;
    struct nod* unu = NULL;
    struct nod* doi = NULL;
    struct nod* p = NULL;
    struct nod* n = NULL;
    unu = (struct nod*)malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    doi = (struct nod*)malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    trei = (struct nod*)malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    p = (struct nod*)malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    n = (struct nod*)malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
    unu->nr = 1;
    unu->next = doi;
    doi->nr = 2;
    doi->next = trei;
    trei->nr = 3;
    trei->next = NULL;
    p = unu;
    int meniu = 0;
    while(1)
    {
        printf("1. Read list");
        scanf("%d", meniu);
        switch(meniu)
        {
        case(2):
            read(p);
            break;
        }
    }
    printf("%d", p->nr);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to allocate memory for `p` as you're assigning it the value of `unu`

Comment: None of your `printf` calls output an end of line character - `\n` - which is used to flush the output

Comment: `scanf("%d", meniu);` should be `scanf("%d", &meniu);`

Comment: Since I am new to Linked List I was expecting to make a mistake declarating them and I totally ignored something as obvious as scanf declaration where I misspelled the "&". I am sorry and thank you !

Comment: `read` is the name of a system/library function. To prevent unexpected behavior, do not name your own functions the same as library functions. Name it e.g. `myRead`.

Comment: Change `while(p->next != NULL )` to `while(p != NULL )` (or even `while (p)`) and you can get rid of the extra `printf()` in `read()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions, no complete fix.

No need to initialize your pointers to NULL, just define and initialize in one step.  Also, don't cast from **void***, which is what **malloc** returns.  C lets you cast back and forth from void pointers implicitly; every cast is an opportunity for error.

```
struct nod* trei = malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
struct nod* unu  = malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
struct nod* doi  = malloc(sizeof(struct nod));
```

It's not clear to me that `n` and `p` need allocation.  I think you mean them to point to allocated nodes.

You can use c99 syntax to initalize your structures in one statement.  I think this form is much clearer.

```
*unu = (struct nod) { .nr = 1, .next = doi };
*doi = (struct nod) { .nr = 2, .next = trei };
*trei = (struct nod) { .nr = 3, .next = NULL };
```

Do yourself a favor and don't call your function **read** unless you
mean to override the standard **read**(2) function.  You're not
reading, you're reporting.  Maybe call it "print".

The loop is awkward.  You want

```
while(p != NULL )
{
    printf("%d", p->nr);
    p=p->next;
}
```

for two reasons:

1. to guard against the passed `p` being NULL
2. to print `trei`

When `p` points to `trei`, `p->next` is NULL.  You don't want to exit
the loop then; you want to print `trei`, assign `p = p->next`, and
test `p`.  Then you can delete the `printf("%d", p->nr);` after the
loop, as you must, because `p` will be NULL.  :-)

I don't see anything else wrong with your "read" function, no reason
it wouldn't print your data.  I'd sprinkle a few more printf
statements in, and call **fflush**(3) each time, to make sure you see
them.  I bet your program isn't doing what you think it is.  Not to
worry, though.  If you like programming, you'll find that pretty
normal.